# Displaying HTML in a textarea once it has been formatted

Tags: php, html, function, textarea

I've used a script to transform line breaks into `<li>` tags in a textarea using PHP, I now want to be able to output the stored content (in `<li>` ) tags not formatted. So it would just appear as if you'd written it originally.

I'm echoing the row into the textarea but naturally it outputs the HTML as well.

Does anyone know of a function or method to strip the tags and replace them with the originally defined line breaks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer:
Do not format text **before** storing it in the database, keep it in it's original form (but do check for dodgy characters etc) and convert it to HTML upon display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do it that way.
Do not transform linebreaks to tags before storing your data but convert it right before printing it onto HTML page.
That's usual way of doing such things.

Comment: Hi, I assumed that doing it pre-upload would be more efficient because the data is being output on several different pages. Will try your suggestion thouhgh.

Comment: Mr S. is correct. It would be useful to filter any nasties out of the input before storing though.

Comment: The usual for more popular / resource heavy applications is to store both versions: unaltered & ready for view (and update the html/ready one on alteration of the 'source' one of course). Be it also in the database or in another cache, but converting somewhat static data over and over again is of course a waste.

Comment: @Wrikken write all your sites in pure HTML. otherwise it will be a waste

Comment: Indeed, it's called a push of static content via a CDN, welcome to the real world my lovely rustbucket :)

Comment: @Wrikken go deliver dynamic HTML block on a page using a CDN

Comment: Can't take it can you? :P As long as you're fine with storing HTML-fragments there is of course nothing wrong with using a CDN, a little glue either server-side or client-sided, and voilàs, you are dynamically including other content, without anyone ever being the wiser. (Why do you think more volatile fragments like conversations & comments are often loaded in asynchronously?)

Comment: @Wrikken server-side will make your CDN rant irrelevant, and client side havevery limited use. In fact, making conversation loaded from another host makes very little sense.

Comment: You're just cranky you didn't deliver the 'holier than thou'-est answer this time. Mix & match content from CDN's is still very relevant, but even on one server having prefab portions of HTML ready instead of building them is still very nice load-wise. Let's ask it like this: what's your argument of NOT caching generated HTML(-portions) of a frequently requested page? Masochism? Bragging rights about load on your server?

Comment: @Wrikken every performance boost has it's price. I do not pursue best performance at any cost. I'd bother with these poor lists only when they become a bottleneck. And yes, you are right, I'd rather cache rendered block in RAM but have them in database as is.

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br()` is the ootb method for converting newlines to `<br>'s`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Hi, I'm aiming to convert li tags to line breaks, I'm not sure if nlb2r() can do this?

Comment: Hola. you said "I've used a script to transform line breaks into <li> tags" - not entirely sure why you'd not transform them into <br>s (being more semantically correct)

Comment: It is for output purposes - the inputted text is being displayed in a list (it is a method for cooking),